# For what values of $x$ does the series converge: $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For what values of $x$ do the following series converge or diverge

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^n}$$

I tried to solve this using the ratio test where the series converge when

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}x^n} <1$$

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{xn^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} <1$$

but then I am not sure what to do next.

Please give me some ideas or hints on how to solve this question, thanks to anybody who helps.

Comment: Is $x$ assumed to be real or complex?

Comment: @Luis Mendo $x$ is assumed to be real.

Comment: @Lucy, won't the root test easier to apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staring from the last step you have shown we have
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{xn^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} <1.$$
But 
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{xn^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n(n+1)}.$$
As $n \to \infty$, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e.$ Thus the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n(n+1)}=0 \quad \forall x.$$

Comment: Yet the OP arrived to the first expression applying the ratio test, so the above proves *only* the series converges for all non-negative $\;x\;$ , whereas in fact it converges for **any** $\;x\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc I'm not sure how you are restricting the ratio test to positive $x$ only. Because it should be based on $\lim\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$?

Comment: I'm restricting nothing. I just made a point about what the OP did

Answer (score 3):

Use test comparison against geometric series, by noting that for any $n>3|x|$ it holds
$$\frac{|x|^n}{n^n}\leq \left(\frac13\right)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

Upper-bound by a geometric series with ratio between 0 and 1 ... (hover mouse to see more)

> That series will be convergent, and then yours will be assured to converge too because of the direct comparison test.

... (and then some more) ...

> To obtain that convergent geometric series, you may need to remove some initial terms.

---

**Detailed answer**

I assume you ask about [*pointwise convergence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence), that is, convergence of the *numeric* series corresponding to a *fixed* value of $x$. I also assume that $x$ is *complex* in general.

Given $x$, let $n_0$ be an integer greater than $|x|$, and let $a = |x|/n_0$. Then $0<a<1$, and $|x|/n \leq a$ for all $n \geq n_0$. So, removing the $n_0-1$ initial terms (which doesn't affect convergence),
$$
\left| \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n} \right|
\leq \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{|x|^n}{n^n}
\leq \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty a^n.
$$
The latter is a geometric series, which [is absolutely convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) because $0 < a <1$. So, applying the [direct comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Direct_comparison_test) it stems that *for any complex $x$*, the original series is *absolutely convergent*.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
n^n \ge n! \implies \frac{x^n}{n^n} \le \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
and use the comparison test against the series formulation of $e^x$

---

Note the above only works for positive $x$, however consider showing that the series is absolutely convergent for any $x$ using the above inequalities and thus it is convergent for any $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\dfrac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \dfrac{1}{n+1} \left( \dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n < \ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

For the ratio test you have to use absolute value as you're not said what $\;x\;$ , and this also works in the complex case. But in this case the n-th root test is better, I believe::

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{|x|^n}{n^n}}=\frac{|x|}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and the above is true for all $\;x\in\Bbb C\;$ , so the series converges for all the complex.